# Texture not rendering in xcode ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

I am working sample project - that place 3d object on horizontal plane.

1. Dragged .dae in art/scnassetes folder.
2. Converted .dae file to .scn
3. Then tapped created .scn file created folder named car.
4. Applying texture each parts of car

But texture applied to car parts are not rendering in xcode.

Here is the screenshot of my xcode screen:

[image]